# How to extract specific columns in a csv file at a particular date using shell-scripting?

Tags: bash, shell

here is an extract from the csv file
[image: csvfile]

I need to extract extract all columns with date 1/3/06 and having the 6th column 'MISSING PERSON'.

I have naively tried using GREP as such

```
 grep "1/3/06" SacramentocrimeJanuary2006.csv | grep "MISSING PERSON"
```

but dont get the deisred output

Comment: It is always recommended to post samples in text form inside CODE TAGS, please edit your post.

Comment: How is the result incorrect? Your `grep` commands are slightly inexact but they should return exactly the expected data from the sample you're sharing. (Images are extremely inconvenient for sharing textual data, btw.)

Comment: @tripleee..it should only return rows with the date 1/3/06 but it also returns rows with other dates as well

Comment: If you look carefully at the other dates, I suspect it will become obvious what the problem is. (I suspect you see "11/3/06" and "21/3/06")

Comment: Your question does not contain enough information to reliably identify your problem or an actually working fix. You should [edit] it to provide a [mre]; otherwise, it may be closed as unclear or unreproducible.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '/^1\/3\/06$/' && $6=="MISSING PERSON"'  Input_file
```

Change from `awk` to `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}....` in above code in case your Input_file is comma separated and you need output in comma separated fashion.

Comment: I typed it in my terminal but it outputs nothing. Can you please explain what you are doing here. I haven't used awk before